# JNI - Calling Java from C++, Class not found

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

Trying this modified example, my Java code depends on other libraries which I've added in the root directory of the C++ app in a folder called libs.

However,

> jclass mClass = env->FindClass("MyClass");

returns null

I suspect the issue is;

> options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=.;./libs/*.jar";

Whereby I have my MyClass.class on the same level as the C++ solution and the rest of the dependent libraries in a folder called /libs.

When I use a java example class with no dependencies the class is found with no problems.

```
int main()
{

using namespace std;

// Pointer to the JVM (Java Virtual Machine)
JavaVM *jvm;

// Pointer to native interface
JNIEnv *env;

//==================== prepare loading of Java VM ============================

// Initialization arguments
JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;

// JVM invocation options
JavaVMOption* options = new JavaVMOption[1];

// where to find java .class
options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=.;./libs/*.jar";

// minimum Java version
vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;

// number of options
vm_args.nOptions = 1;

vm_args.options = options;

// invalid options make the JVM init fail
vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = false;

//================= load and initialize Java VM and JNI interface ===============

jint rc = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);
delete options;

if (rc != JNI_OK)
{
    if (rc == JNI_EVERSION)
        cerr << "FATAL ERROR: JVM is outdated and doesn't meet requirements" << endl;
    else if (rc == JNI_ENOMEM)
        cerr << "FATAL ERROR: not enough memory for JVM" << endl;
    else if (rc == JNI_EINVAL)
        cerr << "FATAL ERROR: invalid argument for launching JVM" << endl;
    else if (rc == JNI_EEXIST)
        cerr << "FATAL ERROR: the process can only launch one JVM an not more" << endl;
    else
        cerr << "FATAL ERROR:  could not create the JVM instance (error code " << rc << ")" << endl;

    cin.get();
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

jint ver = env->GetVersion();
cout << "JVM load succeeded. \nVersion ";
cout << ((ver >> 16) & 0x0f) << "." << (ver & 0x0f) << endl;

//========== Find Class ==========================

// Try to find the class 
jclass mClass = env->FindClass("MyClass");
if (mClass == nullptr)
{
    cerr << "ERROR: class not found !";
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

cout << "Class MyTest found" << endl;
```

Comment: are you sure the current working directory is correct? Have you tried absolute rather than relative class paths?

Comment: well it works when I use the same method and give it the class with no dependencies